# Binding List in Spring using Thymeleaf. Error: Validation failed for object

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

In the post method, it is returning the error: Validation failed for object.

Some info: Incident has 1 or most exhibits.

**My ExhibitList class**

```
public class ExhibitList {

    private List<Exhibit> exhibits;

    public List<Exhibit> getExhibits() {
        return exhibits;
    }

    public void setExhibits(List<Exhibit> exhibits) {
        this.exhibits = exhibits;
    }

    public void addExhibit(Exhibit exhibit) {
        this.exhibits.add(exhibit);
    }
}
```

**My Incident Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "")
    public String incidentRegister(Model model, Principal principal, @PathParam("id") Long id) {


            Incident incident = new Incident();
            model.addAttribute("incident", incident);

            ExhibitList exhibitList = new ExhibitList();
            model.addAttribute("exhibitList", exhibitList);

        return "incidentRegister";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String incidentRegisterPost(@ModelAttribute("exhibitList") ExhibitList exhibitList,
            @ModelAttribute("incident") Incident incident, @ModelAttribute("exhibit") Exhibit exhibit) throws Exception {


        System.out.println("Size: " + exhibitList.getExhibits().size());
        for (Exhibit exhibit2 : exhibitList.getExhibits()) {
            System.out.println("Description: " + exhibit2.getExhibitDescription());
            System.out.println("Marking: " + exhibit2.getExhibitMarking());
            System.out.println("Remarks: " + exhibit2.getExhibitRemarks());
        }

        return "incidentDetail";
    }
```

**My view**

```
<div class="container main">
    <form th:action="@{/incidentRegister/register}" method="post"
        id="formIncidentRegister" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to register this Incident?')">

<h3>Exhibit Details</h3>

        <div id="exhibitList">
            <div class="form-row item"
                th:each="exhibit, status : ${exhibitList.exhibits}">
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="location">Description</label> <input
                        th:field="*{exhibits[__${status.index}__].exhibitDescription}"
                        type="text" class="form-control" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="location">Marking</label> <input
                        th:field="*{exhibits[__${status.index}__].exhibitMarking}"
                        type="text" class="form-control" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="location">Remarks</label> <input
                        th:field="*{exhibits[__${status.index}__].exhibitRemarks}"
                        type="text" class="form-control" />

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addRow()">Add
                    Exhibit</button>
            </div>
        </div>

</form>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    let addRow = function() {

        let listName = 'exhibits';
        let fieldsNames = [ 'exhibitDescription', 'exhibitMarking',
                'exhibitRemarks' ];
        let rowIndex = document.querySelectorAll('.item').length;

        let row = document.createElement('div');
        row.classList.add('form-row', 'item');

        fieldsNames.forEach((fieldName) => {

            let col = document.createElement('div');
            col.classList.add('form-group', 'col-md-4');

            let label = document.createElement('label');
            if(fieldName === 'exhibitDescription'){
                label.innerHTML = 'Description';
            } else if(fieldName === 'exhibitMarking'){
                label.innerHTML = 'Marking';
            } else{
                label.innerHTML = 'Remarks';
            }

            let input = document.createElement('input');
            input.type = 'text';
            input.classList.add('form-control');
            input.setAttribute('name', listName + '[' + rowIndex + ']' + fieldName);

            col.appendChild(label);
            col.appendChild(input);
            row.appendChild(col);
        });
        document.getElementById('exhibitList').appendChild(row);
    };
    //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {

    });
    //]]>
</script>
```

It returns an error 'Validation failed for object='exhibitList'. Error count: 3'. How do i go about retrieving the values of exhibit(s) from the list.

Thank you in advance.

Update 1

**My Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "")
    public String incidentRegister(Model model, Principal principal, @PathParam("id") Long id) {

...

List<Exhibit> exhibitList = new ArrayList<>();
            ExhibitsCreationDto exhibitForm = new ExhibitsCreationDto(exhibitList);
            exhibitForm.addExhibit(new Exhibit());

            model.addAttribute("form", exhibitForm);
}
```

**My View**

```
<form th:action="@{/incidentRegister/register}" method="post"
        th:object="${form}" id="formIncidentRegister"
        onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to register this Incident?')">

<h3>Exhibit Details</h3>

        <div id="exhibitList">
            <div class="form-row item"
                th:each="exhibit, status : ${form.exhibits}">

                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="location">Description</label> <input
                        th:field="*{exhibits[__${status.index}__].exhibitDescription}"
                        type="text" class="form-control" required="required"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="location">Marking</label> <input
                        th:field="*{exhibits[__${status.index}__].exhibitMarking}"
                        type="text" class="form-control" required="required"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="location">Remarks</label> <input
                        th:field="*{exhibits[__${status.index}__].exhibitRemarks}"
                        type="text" class="form-control" required="required"/>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addRow()">Add
                    Exhibit</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <p></p>

        <div class="form-group ">
            <button type="submit"
                class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block login-button">Register</button>
        </div>

        <hr />

        <div class="form-group ">
            <a class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block login-button"
                th:href="@{/incidentQuery}">Cancel</a>
        </div>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

...

    let addRow = function() {

        let listName = 'exhibits';
        let fieldsNames = [ 'exhibitDescription', 'exhibitMarking',
                'exhibitRemarks' ];
        let rowIndex = document.querySelectorAll('.item').length;

        let row = document.createElement('div');
        row.classList.add('form-row', 'item');

        fieldsNames.forEach((fieldName) => {

            let col = document.createElement('div');
            col.classList.add('form-group', 'col-md-4');

            let label = document.createElement('label');
            if(fieldName === 'exhibitDescription'){
                label.innerHTML = 'Description';
            } else if(fieldName === 'exhibitMarking'){
                label.innerHTML = 'Marking';
            } else{
                label.innerHTML = 'Remarks';
            }

            let input = document.createElement('input');
            input.type = 'text';
            input.classList.add('form-control');
            input.id = listName + rowIndex + '.' + fieldName;
            input.setAttribute('name', listName + '[' + rowIndex + ']' + fieldName);

            col.appendChild(label);
            col.appendChild(input);
            row.appendChild(col);
        });
        document.getElementById('exhibitList').appendChild(row);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: add `th:object="${exhibitList}"` in your `form` tag

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. There's still the same error 'Validation failed for object='exhibitList'. Error count: 3'

Comment: Can you upload full trace of your error?

Comment: Its just a html error ' Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Jun 06 16:06:02 SGT 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Validation failed for object='exhibitList'. Error count: 3'

Comment: If you are editing: shouldn't you be adding a value in your inputs to show the current one? If you are adding new elements: why are you sending a list?

Comment: @Jorge.V, yes i am adding a list of exhibits. I am just following the method from the following link [https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-list]. What should i do then?

Answer (score 1):

add `th:object="${exhibitList}"` in your form tag  and modify your controller like this as you don't have any constructor in your class. So when you are initializing `ExhibitList` class, all of its attributes are null as well as the list too. And you can't get an index of a list which is null.

```
ExhibitList exhibitList = new ExhibitList();

List<Exhibit> itemList= new ArrayList<>();
exhibitList.setsetExhibits(itemList);
model.addAttribute("exhibitList", exhibitList);



  @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)


       public String incidentRegisterPost(@ModelAttribute("exhibitList") ExhibitList exhibitList,BindingResult bindingResult) throws Exception {



            System.out.println("Size: " + exhibitList.getExhibits().size());
          // others

            return "incidentDetail";
    }
```

Comment: I've tried. It still give Validation failed for object='exhibitList'. Error count: 3 error

Comment: I have updated my answer. as I have not found `Incident` and `Exhibit` in your form, I removed that from the method parameter.

Comment: It will be easier to detect actual problem if you provide full trace of error from the console of your ide.

Comment: Hi, its submitting now with size=1 but the input fields are null.

Comment: Tried printing the values of the exhibit but its null but the exhibitlist size =1. I have init the itemList like you have recommended.

Comment: Then I think you have still  some problem remaining in the html part.

Comment: Can you check inspecting your form in browser if your desierd input field have correct index or not. like you should have `exhibits[0].exhibitDescription`